# css filter brightness on image but not text overlay

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to show dimmed images unless on hover, while keeping the overlay text pure white all the time.  I have the following:

css:

```
.transition-item
{
    filter: brightness(75%);
}

.transition-item:hover
{
    filter: brightness(100%) !important;
}

.image-item img
{
  width: 200px;
}

.category-caption
{
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 70px;
    margin-top: -91px;
    z-index: 10;
    text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="transition-item">
  <div class="image-item">
    <img src="https://live.staticflickr.com/5480/12139930183_f027b035ad_h.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="category-caption">
    <h2>Testing</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

While the brightness effects work, it also effects the image.  Can also be seen as a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jamesjohnmcguire/xvray348/6/)

I have tried moving the text overlay out of being a child of 'transition-item'. like so:

```
<div class="transition-item">
  <div class="image-item">
    <img src="https://live.staticflickr.com/5480/12139930183_f027b035ad_h.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
  <div class="category-caption">
    <h2>Testing</h2>
  </div>
```

It keeps the text pure white, but upon direct hover on the text, the brightness effect on the image is lost.

**Is there a way to get the brightness on the image and the pure white text of the overlay working together?**

My fallback would be to use 2 different static images already saved with different brightness and switch them using `display: none.`

I have seen some similar questions and approaches, but none with solutions as specific as I need.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also reset filter on h2 on :hover

```css
.transition-item,
.transition-item:hover h2 /* added lukily it starts from a parent set at 100% */{
  filter: brightness(75%);
}

.transition-item:hover {
  filter: brightness(100%);
}

.image-item img {
  width: 200px;
}

.category-caption {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 70px;
  margin-top: -91px;
  z-index: 10;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="transition-item">
  <div class="image-item">
    <img src="https://live.staticflickr.com/5480/12139930183_f027b035ad_h.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="category-caption">
    <h2>Testing</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

or hover selecting only img ?

```css
.transition-item img{
  filter: brightness(75%);
}

.transition-item:hover img {
  filter: brightness(100%);
}

.image-item img {
  width: 200px;
}

.category-caption {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 70px;
  margin-top: -91px;
  z-index: 10;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="transition-item">
  <div class="image-item">
    <img src="https://live.staticflickr.com/5480/12139930183_f027b035ad_h.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="category-caption">
    <h2>Testing</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you may be on to something, but not quite right yet.  Perhaps, I wasn't clear enough.  But ALWAYS (with or without hover) I would like to the text to remain pure white.  Now, before hover, it is darkened a bit.  Effect on image is ok.  So, need a way to keep text pure white.

Comment: Let me know if more clarification needed.

Comment: @Jahmic , i added a second snippet, is that what you tried to do ? i change the selector to select img only

Comment: Great.  The key was the img selector FOLLOWING THE hover like so: 
.transition-item:hover img.